# tmux: occasionally CTRL+B <arrow key> prints character code ([A, [B, [C, or [D) instead of switching panes

Tags: cygwin, tmux

When I try to switch panes in tmux with ctrl+b , tmux sporadically prints the corresponding character code [A, [B, [C, or [D instead of switch panes.

I can do this repeatedly, exactly the same way, 75% the time it will switch properly and the other 25% the time it will print the character code instead.

```
ctrl+b <up arrow>    prints [A
ctrl+b <down arrow>  prints [B
ctrl+b <right arrow> prints [C
ctrl+b <left arrow>  prints [D
```

I'm using cygwin connected to Linux Mint. Tmux is running on Linux mint, and the shell I'm using is bash.

**Edit:** to make this question more search-friendly, I'll add these keywords:

> Terminal outputs character codes open bracket A, open bracket B, open bracket C, open bracket D.

Any ideas?

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using under Cygwin? mintty?

Comment: Terminal emulator is mintty with terminal type set to xterm-256color.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like *tmux*’s `escape-time` is set a bit to low for the quality of connection you have between your Cygwin system and the Linux system.

Many terminals generate the three byte sequence ESC `[` `B` for the down-arrow key. The `escape-time` setting tells *tmux* how long it should wait for a complete sequence after receiving the ESC; if time runs out without receiving a complete sequence, then *tmux* will treat the individual bytes as individual keystrokes (treating C-b ESC as an unbound *tmux* key, and passing `[B` to the active pane’s tty).

So, either you have `escape-time` set to a very low value (which probably works OK when you access *tmux* over strictly local connections), or the connection between the two machines sometimes ends up lagging just a bit longer than your `escape-time` value. You can query the current value with the command `tmux show-options -s | grep escape-time`.

The default is 500 milliseconds; this should work OK in most situations, but might be too short for marginal connections. You might try raising the value of `escape-time`:

```
set-option -s escape-time 1000
```

You can put this in your `~/.tmux.conf` file, run it as a `tmux` command in a shell inside a *tmux* session, or type it directly at *tmux* prompt (opened with C-b `:`). Note: Changes made in `~/.tmux.conf` will not take effect until you re-`source` the file, or restart your *tmux* server.

Comment: +1 for awesome explanation, unfortunately it did not fix the problem. The problem appears to be worse after increasing escape-time :( I should note that the arrow keys do act similarly strangely when attempting to navigate the tmux command line (ctrl+b :). Pressing left to move the cursor on a partially-completed tmux command sometimes erases characters instead of moving the cursor, and I need to press 'i' to be able to type again as if it has vi key bindings and escape was pressed. You're probably right about it being a slow connection problem, but higher escape-times makes it worse.

Comment: Well, that behavior at your *tmux* command-line definitely sounds like a delayed escape sequence problem: the ESC takes you out of insert mode, the `[` is ignored (it is not bound in the `vi-edit` table), and the `D` is the `delete-end-of-line` command. I would not have expected a high `escape-time` to worsen the interrupted-escape-sequence problem; though, it would make *vi*-style bindings inconvenient—you would always need to wait for `escape-time` to elapse after pressing the ESC key (i.e. to exit insert mode), and before starting to type normal-mode commands (e.g. `b` to move back a word).

Comment: Why would this only happen under tmux and not at all when just in bash or a gnu screen session?

Comment: Also, it only occurs when interpreted by tmux (after ctrl+b or while on tmux :command line); I can press the arrow keys repeatedly at the terminal in a tmux window with no problems (bash prompt in tmux session).

Comment: Assume the terminal wants to send the three byte sequence ESC `[` `D`, but it pauses after the first byte. If this occurs after your Prefix, the leading ESC is “eaten” as a bindable key combination (Prefix ESC). In *vi*-style command line editing mode it is “eaten” as the *vi* return-to-normal-mode key. When you are typing at a tty (e.g. *bash* in *tmux*), the ESC is never “eaten”, it it just sent on to the underlying tty as a “separate” key; if the listening process (*bash*) is not as picky about Escape vs. start-of-sequence, then it will simply wait for the `[D` and treat it as a left arrow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this problem as well; it's definitely specific to the arrow keys (and probably cygwin) 
For the time being I decided to just unbind the arrow keys and move the select-pane commands elsewhere, and the new key bindings work flawlessly. Not a very satisfying solution though. I'd love to hear if anyone figures out what is going on.